# Name for a class of problems solvable in $n^{O(\log \log n)}$

Tags: complexity-theory, reference-request

[Isomorphism testing](https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=RjB40FbSDo4C&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=isomorphism+planes+designs+babai&source=bl&ots=h_4kwQ6zXo&sig=mu4bhEvIBMiTRgQDvoksG1qmxbY&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=isomorphism%20planes%20designs%20babai&f=false) of projective planes can be done in $n^{O(\log \log n)}$. This class is contained in quasi-polynomial time. I would like to know more about this class and natural problems in it.

> Is there a standard name for this class of problems?

Also, I am looking for a reference (or survey) that gives other natural problems (without known polynomial-time algorithms) in this class.

Comment: You mentioned sub-exponential time but not quasi-polynomial time, so I figured I'd mention the latter. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes. I will edit it.